Inductance Computed As Length in Historical Document
In "Formulas and Tables for the Calculation of Mutual and Self-inductance.", many equations compute the inductance of an arrangement as a length.  For example, Equation 95, on p. 150, states,
$$
L= 2l \left[ \log \left( \frac{2l}{\rho} - \frac{3}{4} \right) \right]
$$
where l and ρ  are length and radius respectively.
Later in the book, on p. 160, the book states,
$$L = 2000 \left( \log_e 20000 - \frac{3}{4} \right) = 18307.0 \, \text{cm}$$
$$= 18.307 \, \text{microhenrys}$$
As you  can see, the author has divided the result of the computation, which is in centimeters, by 100 to convert it to microhenries.
My understanding is that,
$$1 \, \text{H} = 1 \, \frac{\text{kg} \cdot \text{m}^2}{\text{A}^2 \cdot \text{s}^2} = 1 \, \Omega \cdot \text{s} = 1 \, \frac{\text{V} \cdot \text{s}}{\text{A}} = 1 \, \frac{\mu \cdot N^2 \cdot A}{l} = 1 \, \frac{\text{J}}{\text{C}^2} = 1 \, \frac{\text{Wb}}{\text{A}}$$
How are they converting a length into a measure of inductance?  How are these units equivalent?    Furthermore, shouldn't the equations for  inductance some how feature a μ0 term somehow?  At first I thought maybe they just omitted the μ0 term, but μ0 ≈ 1.2566370614 × 10-6 H/m, so it couldn't be a straight conversion that excluded that term.
References
1 Rosa, E. B., Grover, F. W. (1912). Formulas and Tables for the Calculation of Mutual and Self-inductance. United States: U.S. Government Printing Office. Available online here.

Why does your 2nd formula equate to $18307.0 cm$? And how can that distance in cm equate to 18.3 microhenries? An image would have been less problematic in terms of believability. The first formula is approximately correct BTW and assumes a relative permeability of air/vacuum.

Blame George Campbell and electrical engineers for the coherent plan of units MKS to avoid problems like this. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MKS_units

Four outstanding achievements of Campbell were (a) the loading coil, (b) the electric wave filter, (c) the professional popularization of the Fourier Integral in electrical engineering, and (d) the most effective propagation of the Giorgi system, later called the MKS system, and more recently further superseded in name.
Brainerd, John G. “Some Unanswered Questions.” Technology and Culture 11, no. 4 (1970): 601–3. https://doi.org/10.2307/3102695

The author is using cgs units, where \$\mu_0\$ is defined as 1 Abhenries/cm. Since units of Abhenries are cm the number is dimensionless.
The inductance has the units of Abhenries (cm). Converting to Henrys involves a division by \$10^9\$ (not \$10^8\$) which straightens out the units (consider it to be in cm/H or multiply by \$10^{-9}\$ H/cm).
See, for example,  Table 4 in Classical Electrodynamics 3rd Edition (Jackson).
The numbers are derived from theory (Biot-Savart law) with some geometrical constructions. Earlier articles by Rosa go into it.

Current can be defined in terms of the attractive force upon two conductors carrying that current. More specifically, an ampere may be defined, and was defined from 1948 until 2019, as "that constant current which, if maintained in two straight parallel conductors of infinite length, of negligible circular cross section, and placed 1 metre apart in vacuum, would produce between these conductors a force equal to \$2\times10^{−7}\$ newton per metre of length" per Wikpedia
The formula for the force per length created by two straight conductors of small diameter and infinite length a distance r apart, and carrying currents I_1 and I_2 is given by
$$\frac{F}{l}=\frac{\mu_0}{2\pi}\frac{I_1I_2}{r}$$
If \$\mu_0\$ is treated as a dimensionless unit quantity, we have
$$\frac{F}{l}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{I_1I_2}{r}$$
We are justified in making this assumption because on p150 of "Formulas and Tables for the Calculation of Mutual and Self-inductance."
it states:

Where the permeability of the wire is \$\mu\$, and that of the medium outside is unity...

If the same current \$I\$ is flowing through both conductors, we have
$$\frac{F}{l}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{I^2}{r}$$
Letting \$k=\frac{l}{r}\$ we have
$$F = k\frac{1}{2\pi}I^2$$
Going back to the definition of an ampere as that constant current which, if maintained in two straight parallel conductors of infinite length, of negligible circular cross section, and placed 1 metre apart in vacuum, would produce between these conductors a force equal to \$2\times10^{−7}\$ newton per metre of length, we have
$$2\times10^{−7} \text{N} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\text{A}^2$$
or
$$1 \text{A}^2= 4\pi\times10^{-7}\text{N} = 4\pi\times10^{-7}\frac{\text{kg}\cdot\text{m}}{\text{s}^2}$$
Plugging this definition of ampere (squared) into the formula
$$1 \text{H} = 1 \frac{\text{kg} \cdot \text{m}^2}{\text{A}^2 \cdot \text{s}^2} $$
gives
$$1 \text{H} = 1 \frac{\text{kg} \cdot \text{m}^2}{4\pi\times10^{-7}\frac{\text{kg}\cdot\text{m}}{\text{s}^2}\cdot \text{s}^2}$$
or
$$4\pi\times10^{-7} \text{H} = 1 \text{m}$$
Using different (essentially arbitrary, but judiciously chosen) values of \$\mu_0\$ will result in different units for the henry.
In the manual cited, the equation was made:
$$18307.0\text{cm}=18.307\mu\text{H}$$
which is equivalent to the assertion that
$$10^{-7}\text{H}=1\text{m}$$
Where did the \$4\pi\$ go? My answer to that riddle is that although the formula requires a length as an input, it doesn't give a length as an output, but an inductance as an output. Thus, the inclusion of the units "cm" in the intermediate result of the equation
$$L = 2000 \left( \log_e 20000 - \frac{3}{4} \right) = 18307.0 \, \text{cm}= 18.307 \, \text{microhenrys}$$
is misleading at best and an error at worst. The dimension of the intermediate result is indeed equivalent to a length, but the units are off by \$4\pi\$.
I have verified the calculation of self-inductance of a copper wire of length 1000 cm, and diameter 2 mm, using two separate calculators, one at allaboutcircuits.com and the other at eeweb.com and both agree that the result is approximately 18.3 uH.

I have an old electrodynamics book somewhere in which the preface explains the use of cgs vs. SI units and mentions that the 4π factors keep showing up in one but not the other.

If you get the chance, the name of the book would be appreciated.

"Quantum Mechanics" by Merzbacher.  "One small but radical departure must still be mentioned, because it concerns an emotionally charged subject: I have used the rationalized mks system of electromagnetic units. This choice was made not because I have any ax to grind, but solely because most of the textbooks on electricity and magnetism which the student is likely to consult employ this system of units. Readers who are irritated by 4π's and $\epsilon_0$'s are assured that only very few equations are "marred" by this unorthodox choice of units."

"The Appendix lists the relevant equations together with their transcription into the Gaussian system of units."
Eugen Merzbacher Chapel Hill, N.C. December 1960

Could have sworn it was "Introduction to Electromagnetic Theory"  by Owen 1963, a book with wonderful hand-drawn illustrations of surface integrals, toroids and such like.

The equation in the book is that most dangerous of equations, an equation in particular units.
You must use the expression with exactly the units given. Otherwise you will get nonsense. There is no point in checking unit consistency...because they aren't.
By the way, these are fits that work pretty well with typical dimensions, but are not directly connected to theory.
